# What is the wrong with my python code_ very beginner question?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

class Test: 

    note = 10 

if note >= 10:
            print("yes")
    else:
            print("NO")
```

---

The output is:

```
env: /Users/mac/Downloads/Ex_Files_Python_EssT/Test.py: 
Permission denied
```

Why I have got this message?

Comment: Exactly what did you do to run this code?

Answer (score 1):

Make the python file executable

chmod +x Test.py

Comment: There is a _lot_ more wrong with this code. This will only run the OP into the next issue.

Comment: I know the code has errors. Right now was trying to give solution for the error Permission denied :D

Answer (score 0):

Why do you have to include the logic inside a class?

note = 10

if note >= 10:
            print("yes")
    else:
            print("NO")

Just this will do, remove the class

Comment: Please format your answer. Btw there is no need of two answers from one person. You can add it to the existing answer.

Comment: Unfortunately,  I have tried 

#!/usr/bin/env python3

note = 10

if note >= 10: print("yes") else: print("NO")                                                   
and I got :                                                                                                                                                                                                                               env: /Users/mac/Downloads/Ex_Files_Python_EssT/Text-4.py: Permission denied                                                                                                 
I ues komodo edit 11

Answer (score 0):

Why you use "env" from system directory? If you change first line of script code will working. May be some strange settings in you OS or you try strange using python env.

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7

class Test:
    note = 10

    if note >= 10:
       print("yes")
    else:
       print("NO")
```

Comment: class Test:
 
    note = 14
 
    if note >= 10:
        print("Congratulations.. you passed the test!")
 
    else:
        print("Sorry.. you failed the test!")



I wrote this in  Jupiter by anaconda  the output is working
I wrote this in Komodo Edit 11 

#!/usr/bin/python3


class Test:
 
    
    note = 14
 
    
    if note >= 10:
        print("Congratulations.. you passed the test!")
 
    else:
        print("Sorry.. you failed the test!")


I received this message 


env: /Users/mac/Downloads/Ex_Files_Python_EssT/Test_4.py: Permission denied